How to create a proper system of searching/adding non-existent data to a txt file in c++?
I'm trying to create a system, which allows me to write data to a txt file if it doesn't exist in it. For some reason, it doesn't work with existing data, and I can't seem to understand why. It has no problem writing data to the file, however, it doesn't see the existing data.
Here's the code:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    bool foundname = false;
    ifstream file("names-genders.txt");
    string name, surname, gender, checkbuffer;
    cout << "Name, surname: ";
    cin >> name >> surname;
    while (getline(file, checkbuffer)) {
        if (checkbuffer.find(name) != string::npos) {
            gender = checkbuffer.substr(checkbuffer.find_last_of(' ') + 1);
            foundname = true;
        }
    }
    if (not(foundname)) {
        {
            file.close();
            ofstream file("names-genders.txt", ios::app);
            cout << "Name not found in database. Please enter the gender by hand: ";
            cin >> gender;
            file << "\n" + name + " " + gender;
        }
    }
    file.close();
    //there is more code here, but it is not related to the issue
    cout << "Hi";
}

The "names-genders.txt" is the file in the same folder as the project, and it contains two lines:
Alexander male
Fedor male

After typing "Fedor" on the third launch, it gives me the "Name not found...." output, and adds third line with the inputted data.
Also, all the code after this part doesn't work. It seems like the compiler doesn't see anything after it, or something like that.
Tried rewriting it multiple times, but nothing seemed to work. Most likely, I don't see, or don't know, something important that stops it from working. Adding "break" when the suiting item is found also gave no result.
For a test I removed all code after this part, and added a useless "Hi" to the output, but for some reason, the code finishes the work, after inputting the data, and does not output "Hi."

You should break out of the loop once you find the name.

Stack Overflow Usage Note: "it doesn't work" and its many variants are the kiss of death for a question unless it is followed up with a detailed description of the program behaviour you expected and the program behaviour observed. By itself "it doesn't work" Doesn't tell us anything that asking a question here didn't already tell us: That you have a problem you need solved.

Side note: Often writing down the expected alongside the observed is all you need to do to shake loose the braincells holding the answer to the question.

This would be a good opportunity to learn how to use a debugger. Step through the loop that reads from the file, print checkbuffer, and notice when it doesn't do what you expect.

Don't use checkbuffer.find(), it will match anywhere in the line. Split the line info name and gender, then check if the name equals the one you're searching for.

When you call file.close() at the end, you're closing the input file. You never close the output file that's opened in the if block, because that variable's scope is just the if.

No better time for a trip to see How to debug small programs (it's a StackOverflow right of passage... :)

When splitting on names, remember that names come in many shapes and sizes, some containing spaces. Your trick of looking for the final space on the line is a reasonably good way to perform the split, but cin >> name >> surname; is going to fail over a name like Victor Von Doom, and he's not someone to accidentally slight by messing up his name.

Database
You are basically implementing a simple database, but you could use a bit of database theory to make your program work better.
Fixed Length Records
Databases use fixed length records to make reading and writing easier and faster.  For example, if each record is 256 characters wide, then your 3rd record starts at (3-1) * 256.  {The -1 is because the first record is at 0.}  You can use block reads and writes since you know the record length, e.g. istream::read().
Separation Characters
You should use some other character, like ';', to separate columns.  This allows you to use std::getline(my_file, my_text, ';') to read everything up to the semicolon (including spaces).  Using one record per text line is advantageous over repeated columns per line.
Libraries & Existing Examples
You are basically using the CSV format, which is to use separation characters to separate columns.  Search the internet for "C++ CSV Example" or "C++ CSV library".  There are many libraries you can use and plenty of exist examples for you to compare to.
There are other human readable formats you may want to research:  XML, JSON, INI.  They all have libraries and examples to help you out.
Accessing the Data
Many relational databases use two tables for the data.  The first table contains all the records, unsorted.  The second table is an index table that is sorted by a key column (field).  In C++, you could use something like std::map<key-type, unsigned-int>.  The unsigned-int field will be the index into the first table.  Index tables allow you to develop different sorting parameters without having to change the first table.
Using A Database
You may want to consider using an actual database.  There are many databases, range from small to huge and free to paid.  If this is to be a serious application, consider using an existing database or spreadsheet.

Actually the whole table need not always be loaded into memory. A record index map(std::vector<index_type>) would be sufficient to keep the relative ordering of records, avoiding memory exhaustion.

The quick fix: break out of the loop
There is a lot of good information in the answer by @Thomas Matthews. I up-voted it.
If, however, you want to stay with the basic design you already have, then the first comment (above), by @Barmar, gives you the quick fix:

You should break out of the loop once you find the name.

Here is what that looks like:
while (getline(file, checkbuffer)) {
    if (checkbuffer.find(name) != string::npos) {
        gender = checkbuffer.substr(checkbuffer.find_last_of(' ') + 1);
        foundname = true;
        break;  // <------------ break out of loop
    }
}

With that change, the program in the OP will run.
Split file lines into name and gender fields
@Barmar also points out that the program contains a subtle bug:

Don't use checkbuffer.find(), it will match anywhere in the line. Split the line info name and gender, then check if the name equals the one you're searching for.

With checkbuffer.find(), the name could end up matching part of the gender field. That is why you need to split up the file lines. After you split off the name field, it is still wrong to use member function find. Consider what happens, for instance, when you search for the name "John" and the data file contains both "John" and "Johnny".
The program below uses a dedicated function to look up a name in the file. When it finds a name, it returns the corresponding gender. Otherwise, it returns the empty string.
In case the file cannot be opened, look_up_gender also returns the empty string. When the file does not exist, therefore, it will be created, when a new record is later "appended" to it. This matches the behavior of the OP.
std::string look_up_gender(
    std::string const& file_name, 
    std::string const& name)
{
    std::string s;
    std::ifstream file{ file_name };
    while (std::getline(file, s)) {
        std::string_view const sv{ trim_whitespace_view(s) };
        auto const len_name{ sv.find_last_of(' ') };
        if (len_name == std::string_view::npos) {
            throw std::runtime_error{ "look_up_gender: "
                "could not find space in record" };
        }
        if (sv.substr(0u, len_name) == name) {
            return std::string(sv.substr(len_name + 1u));
        }
    }
    return "";
}

Each line of the file is parsed using the same find_last_of(' ') operation that was used in the OP. In function look_up_gender, however, the result is stored as the length of the name field:
auto const len_name{ sv.find_last_of(' ') };

len_name is then used to break out the name and gender.

sv.substr(0u, len_name) is the name field
sv.substr(len_name + 1u) is the gender field

Note that the file is closed automatically, by the destructor of std::ifstream.
Append new records to the file
The program below also uses a dedicated function to append new records at the end of the file.
It expects that every line of the file ends with '\n'. Unlike the OP, therefore, it appends a newline character after the record it writes. In the OP, the newline is appended before writing a new record.
void append_to_file(
    std::string const& file_name,
    std::string const& name,
    std::string const& gender)
{
    std::ofstream file(file_name, std::ios::app);
    file << name << ' ' << gender << '\n';
}

As above, the file is closed automatically, by the destructor of std::ofstream.
Refactoring function main
Using the two functions above, along with a couple of helpers, trim_whitespace_view and get_string_from_user, it is a simple matter to refactor function main:
int main() {
    std::string const file_name{ "names-genders.txt" };
    std::string const name{ get_string_from_user("Name: ") };
    std::string const surname{ get_string_from_user("Surname: ") };
    std::string gender{ look_up_gender(file_name, name) };
    if (gender.empty()) {
        gender = get_string_from_user("Name not found in database. "
            "Please enter the gender by hand: ");
        append_to_file(file_name, name, gender);
    }
}

Function get_string_from_user addresses a problem that was identified in the comment by @user4581301:

When splitting on names, remember that names come in many shapes and sizes, some containing spaces. Your trick of looking for the final space on the line is a reasonably good way to perform the split, but cin >> name >> surname; is going to fail over a name like Victor Von Doom, and he's not someone to accidentally slight by messing up his name.

get_string_from_user uses std::getline, rather than std::cin >> name, so it can handle names that contain spaces.
A complete program
Here is the complete program:
// main.cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

std::string_view trim_whitespace_view(std::string_view sv) noexcept
{
    // Trim leading and trailing whitespace from string_view `sv`.
    enum : std::string_view::size_type { zero, one };
    auto const first{ sv.find_first_not_of(" \f\n\r\t\v") };
    if (first == std::string_view::npos)
        return sv.substr(zero, zero);
    auto const last{ sv.find_last_not_of(" \f\n\r\t\v") };
    return sv.substr(first, (last - first + one));
}
std::string get_string_from_user(std::string const& prompt)
{
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << prompt;
        if (std::string s; !std::getline(std::cin, s)) {
            throw std::runtime_error{ "get_string_from_user: "
                "`std::getline` failed" };
        }
        else if (std::string_view const sv(trim_whitespace_view(s)); 
            sv.empty()) {
            std::cout << "Entries cannot be blank.\n\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout.put('\n');
            return std::string(sv);
        }
    }
}
std::string look_up_gender(
    std::string const& file_name, 
    std::string const& name)
{
    std::string s;
    std::ifstream file{ file_name };
    while (std::getline(file, s)) {
        std::string_view const sv{ trim_whitespace_view(s) };
        auto const len_name{ sv.find_last_of(' ') };
        if (len_name == std::string_view::npos) {
            throw std::runtime_error{ "look_up_gender: "
                "could not find space in record" };
        }
        if (sv.substr(0u, len_name) == name) {
            return std::string(sv.substr(len_name + 1u));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
void append_to_file(
    std::string const& file_name,
    std::string const& name,
    std::string const& gender)
{
    std::ofstream file(file_name, std::ios::app);
    file << name << ' ' << gender << '\n';
}
int main() {
    std::string const file_name{ "names-genders.txt" };
    std::string const name{ get_string_from_user("Name: ") };
    std::string const surname{ get_string_from_user("Surname: ") };
    std::string gender{ look_up_gender(file_name, name) };
    if (gender.empty()) {
        gender = get_string_from_user("Name not found in database. "
            "Please enter the gender by hand: ");
        append_to_file(file_name, name, gender);
    }
}
// end file: main.cpp

